# Derivative of vector w.r.t. scalar

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am struggling with backpropagating BatchNormalization. For that, I would like to take the partial derivative of a vector valued function with respect to a scalar. The simplified function looks like this.

$$
\vec{f}(\vec{x}, y) = \vec{x} + (y,y,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} + y
\\ 
x_{2} + y
\\ 
x_{3} + y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can see that
$$\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{y}} = 1$$
And following [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419496/derivative-of-a-vector-with-respect-to-scalar/419507#419507) post the partial derivative for the vector-valued function should equal

$$\frac{\partial{\vec{f}}}{\partial{y}} = \begin{bmatrix}
1
\\ 
1
\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

But from my knowledge of backprop I thought that the derivative should have the same shape as the variable which is obviously not the case because $dim(\frac{\partial{\vec{f}}}{\partial{y}}) \neq dim(y)$

But let's say we have a second function $g(\vec{f}) = g(f_{1}(x_{1}, y), \cdots)$, then with the multivariable variable chain rule we would obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{\partial{f_{i}}}{\partial{y}} = 3
$$

I would like to ask if my intuition is correct.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: you cannot sum a vector $x(3 \times 1)$ and a scalar $y$.

Comment: You CAN, it just doesn't mean anything on its own ($\textbf{x}+y=\textbf{x}+y$). In any case, I think the OP meant $\textbf{x}+(y,y,y)$.

Comment: In this case, define $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$, compute the $3 \times 3$ matrix of partial derivatives $$ \frac{\partial f^T}{\partial y}(x,y) $$ and evaluate it at $y=(1,1,1)$, which gives the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.

Comment: Sorry, I meant and element wise addition such as $\mathbf{x} + (y,y,y)$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean
$$\textbf{f}(\textbf{x},y)=\textbf{x}+(y,y,y)=(x_1+y,x_2+y,x_3+y)$$
In which case
$$\frac{\partial\textbf{f}}{\partial y}=\left(\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y}\right)=(1,1,1)$$
The dimensions of $y$ are not particularly relevant, and in general the dimensions of the variable you take the derivative with respect to does not matter. In general, for any scalar $x$ and vector valued function $\textbf{f}$, $dim\left(\frac{\partial \textbf{f}}{\partial x}\right)=dim(\textbf{f})\neq dim(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an element wise addition. Thank you for the answer.